# how to trigger a php script with an argument from a javascript thats in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display images on a webpage as a gallery but i only want albums, each folder is an album and you select the album with the link menu
so i parse the path to a function that then should then run a php script to return all the names of the images in that album, so far this is what i have.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-container" style="height: 500px;">
  <div id="content" style="height: 500px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
      <h1> <span>The Gallery</span> </h1>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="" id="here">Gallery</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld01">photos</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld02">photos</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld03">photos</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld04">photos</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Back to home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="album-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).data("albumid");
          $(".album-container").empty();
          LoadGallery(id);
          return false;
        });
      });

      function LoadGallery(id) {
          alert('Loading gallery #' + id);
          $(".album-container").load("getimages.php?dirpath=id,function() {
            var reciverParameters = $(".album - container ").html();
            var parser = new Array();
            parser = reciverParameters.split(", ");
            alert(parser);
            })
            /*
            var curimg=0

            function rotateimages(){
                document.getElementById("
              album - container ").setAttribute("
              id "+galleryarray[curimg]);
                curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0;
            }

            window.onload=function(){
                setInterval("
              rotateimages()
              ", 2500)
            }
            })
            */
        }
    </script>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$dirname = $_get['dirpath'];

function returnimages($dirname) {
    $pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)";
    $files = array();
    $curimage=0;
    if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
                //Output it as a JavaScript array element
                echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
                $curimage++;
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
    return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
?>
```

Comment: Try using Ajax, in jQuery, `$.post( url ... ) or $.get( url ... )`

Comment: I am new to this and i am not sure how to implement your suggestion, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make some change in both the `php` and `html` code.

**PHP Code**

First of all change the tag `<?` to `<?php`.

The most important change: change the format in which you send the image list to the client. Instead of sending `JavaScript`, send `JSON`, which is intended for this kind of stuff.

To do that, change the `Header` call to this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Then in the function `returnimages`, replace the `echo` line with:

```
$files[] = $dirname . "/" . $file;
```

This will collect the images in the $files array, and that will be returned by the function. Note that you should prefix the file name with the directory name, to have a qualified reference. Also note you don't actually need the `$curimage` variable, because with the `$files[]` notation, you indicate that elements should be added at the end of the array.

This function relies on [`eregi`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) which is deprecated since `php` 5.3. Instead you could use `preg_match`. For that you need to put slashes around your regular expression, like this:

```
$pattern="/(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)/";
```

Then, replace the test with this:

```
if (1 === preg_match($pattern, $file)) {
```

The function's return value should be converted to `JSON` -- this should be the only thing you `echo`:

```
echo json_encode(returnimages($dirname));
```

Note that in your original code, you did not pass the `$dirname` argument, so it could not have worked.

This will make `PHP` return a `JSON` encoded array, which is so much better than sending back a piece of `JavaScript`.

**HTML Code**

Here you need to change the `$(".album-container").load` call by the following:

```
$.getJSON('getimages.php', {dirpath: id}, function(galleryarray) {
    var galleryHtml = [];
    // Go through each element in the returned array (galleryarray) 
    // and build image tags for them
    $.each(galleryarray, function (index, file) {
        // TODO: Add any other `HTML` you need with this image tag
        galleryHtml.push('<img src="' + file + '"/>');
    }):
    // Now put these images inside the container.
    $(".album-container").html(galleryHtml.join(''));
});
```

If this looks all new to you, please read a bit about the [`php json_encode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and maybe even about [`json` in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Also read about the [`jQuery.getJSON` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to understand each parameter and the asynchronous nature of such methods. These pages have examples which should help you further.

Maybe the file references of your images need to be prefixed with some folder... I don't know where you have them stored. But this you can encode in the `img` tags, and maybe you want to add some other `html` or `css` stuff there.

Once the above code works, you will probably want to do more. But this should be the way to move forward.

Comment: Having followed your code and implemented it in to mine it shows no errors but still no images, not to sure what is wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged with `console.log`? I did not test the code, it is just pointing in the right direction. For instance, add `console.log(galleryarray);` in the JS function I provided above, and see what it reports.

Comment: Another thing you can do to debug, is call `getimages.php?dirpath=images/gallery/fld01` directly in your browser (prefix with http:// ... etc) and see if you get the JSON output displayed.

Comment: I am getting galleryarray not defined error, so looking at the code should Var galleryhtm = []; read galleryarray = []; ?

Comment: Having added Var galleryarray = []; that error has gone but now it's showing "not well formed" and is pointing to the path i sending to getimages, if i click on it it shows me the J quarry script.

Comment: `galleryarray` is a parameter, so it is declared. Please try to understand the code: it is provided by `$.getJSON`. `galleryHtml` is an entirely different variable, that is also needed. Please provide the exact line on which you get the error, and the exact error message (with the version of the script  I provided). Make sure that `getimages.php` is correctly spelled, and that it works when you type that in the browser, like I already suggested in my previous comment. Did you try that? Debugging is an art one has to learn...

Comment: Another important remark, you must put your `php` code in a `<?php` tag, not just `<?`, and you have to change the first `php` line to `header('Content-Type: application/json');`  I will add this in my answer.

Comment: ... and I just spotted another bug in your `php` code: you must provide `$dir_name` as an argument when you call `returnimages`. Really, these are the kinds of things you should find easily if you debug your code, by putting `echo` everywhere, checking what gets output, and continue until it works. That is one of the basic skills you need in successful programming.

Comment: Yet another issue: `eregi` is a deprecated function since `php` 5.3, so I have added replacement code for that in my answer. Please take all this into account, and perform the tests I have described in earlier comments.

Comment: You also will want to prefix file names with directory names, to make sure the images will have valid `src` references in your web page. so by now, I have spotted like 4 or 5 bugs/problems in your code, now it's your turn to work on it. :-)

Comment: Hi trincot, i have been through the code with a fine tooth comb and have even checked on the new about what the code does etc.. but i just keep this error message: ReferenceError: galleryarray is not defined
[link](http://localhost/Reggarockaboogie/gallery.html)
Line 111

Comment: Where does it say that? The link is to your local machine, I cannot use that obviously, I don't have the complete code, so line numbers don't help, please provide the exact line itself.

Comment: ReferenceError: galleryarray is not defined
This points to this -> console.log(galleryarray); in gallery.html

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _get in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Reggarockaboogie\getimages.php</b> on
 line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for returnimages(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Reggarockaboogie\getimages
.php on line 22 and defined in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Reggarockaboogie\getimages.php</b> on line <b>5</b
><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: dirname in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Reggarockaboogie\getimages.php</b>
 on line <b>9</b><br />
[]

Comment: About your last error (in `php` I assume), please see my comment "... and I just spotted another bug" above, and make the correction as I describe in my answer. It would be good if you check my complete answer again, to make sure you have not missed anything. This also explains the error about galleryarray, because if your `php` code has errors, the `$getJSON` code will fail as well.

Comment: <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$dirname=$_get["dirpath"];
function returnimages($dirname) {
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)";
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if (1 === preg_match($pattern, $file)) { //if this file is a valid image
 //Output it as a JavaScript array element
$files[$curimage] = $file;
$curimage++;
 }
 }
closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}
echo json_encode(returnimages());
?>

Comment: (1) You did not adapt the regular expression (add slashes) - this makes your `php` code fail; (2) You did not prefix the file with the directory; (3) You don't need to use `$curimage`. Once you have done this, call the php page directly from your browser, like this: `http://localhost/Reggarockaboogie/getimages.php?dirpath=images/gallery/fld01` and see whether you get a nice `JSON` output.

Comment: I am sorry about this but i am not sure when you say add slashes and prefix, i used to program in pure basic but never like this, if i understand right prefix means to add the directory path to the file but not sure were!

Comment: Look in my answer! Please... it is there. Read it. `$pattern="/ .......... /";` I really feel wasting my time, if you do not read my answer!

Comment: I am so sorry i thought i had done that, well the only error i am getting now is The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Comment: You can ignore that error. It is normal with a `JSON` file, as it is not supposed to be rendered by a browser. But what is wrong, is that the web page is empty? It should show something like `[ "images/gallery/fld01/myimage.jpg", "images/gallery/fld01/myotherimage.jpg" ]` If nothing, then please debug your `PHP` code. I guess it is not finding any images in the location where it is looking. You need to dig into this. I cannot help you much with that.

Comment: Thank's i did get rid of the error with if (isset($_GET['$dirpath'])) but like you say no images showing i will have a look at the path to see if it's ok.

Comment: And is `isset($_GET['$dirpath'])` `true`or `false`? Does it loop through files in that folder? Or does it not get there? It should be easy to find that out in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I now see you have a dollar in `$_GET['$dirpath'])`, but that is wrong, the url parameter is without dollar:  `$_GET['dirpath'])`. I let you now. I have other things to do.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for all your help and time and getting me closer to my goal, Regards D.L.C